# Getting list of rows of dashlets on current dashboard in SugarCRM 8.0.0

Tags: javascript, list, metadata, sugarcrm, dashboard

In Sugar 7.8.2, we were able to get a list of the rows (of dashlets) displayed on the current dashboard from `App.controller.layout.model.attributes.metadata.components[0].rows`.

In Sugar 8.0.0, `metadata` can no longer be accessed from `App.controller.layout.model.attributes`.

I've been looking through `App` using Chrome's DevTools console and am yet to come up with anything similar. Are there other ways to reach a list such as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you can receive the rows of the current Dashboard model like this:

```
App.controller.context.get("model").get("metadata").components[0].rows
```

Can also be written as:

```
App.controller.context.attributes.model.attributes.metadata.components[0].rows
```

Comment: Just so others know, `App.controller.context.attributes.model.attributes.metadata.components[0].rows` also works on Sugar 7.8.2, not just on Sugar 8.0.0